# Python: Procedimiento de comprensión de diccionario para contar repeticiones en una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
frutas = ["manzana", "banana", "cereza", "banana", "frutilla"]

repeticiones = {fruta : frutas.count(fruta) for fruta in frutas}

print(repeticiones)
```

Y lo que hace básicamente es encontrar las repeticiones de los items en una lista, funciona, como quiero que funcione, pero hay algo que no entiendo, por ejemplo, con la lista que puse, banana esta dos veces, y cuando se ejecuta el bucle for de repeticiones, el resultado es *{'manzana': 1, 'banana': 2, 'cereza': 1, 'frutilla': 1}* como espero que sea, o mejor dicho como quiero que sea. Lo que no entiendo es, si fruta es cada item de frutas, ¿por qué el output es el diccionario con *'banana': 2* solo una vez, en lugar de dos veces? O sea, en lugar de *{'manzana': 1, 'banana': 2, 'cereza': 1, 'banana': 2, 'frutilla': 1}*

Repito, no hay un error en el codigo, solo quiero entender el procedimiento de la comprensión de lista. Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Porque la segunda vez que encuentra `banana` la clave correspondiente del diccionario ya existe y la sobreescribe...

Comment: Ahhhh, listo, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Eso NO es una propiedad de la comprensión de diccionarios, es una propiedad del diccionario en sí! No puede haber claves repetidas en un diccionario.

Comment: Puedes hacer lo mismo de forma mas eficiente usando [Counter](https://rico-schmidt.name/pymotw-3/collections/counter.html) de python. Solo un aporte

Answer (score 1):

El procedimiento de la comprensión es sencillo no te puede mostrar banana dos veces pues lo que tu compresión devuelve es un diccionario, como los diccionarios trabajan con llave:valor y en caso de asignar un valor a una llave la cual se encuentra en el diccionario se soobrecribe su valor no se añade una nueva llave. Entonces tú comprensión lo que haría es recorrer cada item, si el nombre del item en este caso banana no está en el diccionario lo añade como llave y su correspondiente valor, después continúa con el siguiente item si la llave no se encuentra en el diccionario la crea y le añade un valor que sería la cantidad de veces que la fruta aparece en el arreglo y si aparece soobrecribe la llave con un nuevo valor....

Espero haber aclarado tu duda